# Is checking SharedPreferences every mintue a good idea

Tags: android

I have an AlarmManager which calls a BroadcastReceiver every minute. It is working fine without any problem. The BroadcastReceiver looks up the values existing on a SharedPreferences file. It checks around 4 values every minute. 
I was just wondering if this is taking a toll on the system. And will it eventually make the device slower ?

PS - I cannot reduce the values anymore. That would conflict with my current design. 
Thank You in advance.

PPS - A brief theory regarding the time and speed of SharedPreference would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Write service OR Call BroadcastReceiver by Timer class.

Comment: Not sure if that answers my question. The methods I wrote and the classes I made are working perfectly. I am just worried if it is bombarding the device's resources.

Comment: I'm afraid this may prevent device of entering in IDLE. This may wake up device very often and can drain battery... I'd search/test more about it before using... About resources, I don't see any problem. It does not seem too heavy

Comment: I will be undertaking a stress test now. Will check the battery drain on all my devices for an hour and another test where the app isn't present. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know if [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) drains your battery fast, but what I suggest u to do is remove the AlarmManager part in your code, and use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) instead.

From the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29):

> **Note:** The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

precision timing required either:

> [setRepeating](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) for < API19
>
> [setExact](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) API 19 <
>
> **Note:** only alarms for which there is a strong demand for exact-time delivery (such as an alarm clock ringing at the requested time) should be scheduled as exact. Applications are strongly discouraged from using exact alarms unnecessarily as they **reduce** the OS's ability to minimize **battery** use.

these are both pretty battery consuming.

So u would have to go with:

> [setInexactRepeating](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) for < API 19
>
> **Note:** Schedule a repeating alarm that has inexact trigger time requirements; for example, an alarm that repeats every hour, but not necessarily at the top of every hour. These alarms are more **power-efficient** than the strict recurrences traditionally supplied by setRepeating(int, long, long, PendingIntent), since the system can adjust alarms' delivery times to cause them to fire simultaneously, **avoiding waking the device from sleep more than necessary.**

but this is not very precise for an alarm that has to execute every minute.

So, you're probably best of with a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html):

```
final Handler handler = new Handler()
handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Do your things
    handler.postDelayed( this, 60 * 1000 );
    }
}, 60 * 1000 );
```

Hope this answers your question. If anything isn't correct or should be improved, feel free to edit/add this, or leave a comment below.

Comment: The reason for using the AlarmManager was because the app checks the time and sees if there is an event associated on that particular time. The event is saved in a SharedPreference. Using a handler would defy the primary purpose which would be 'working in the background'.

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't know, srry about that

Comment: My bad, I should have mentioned what happens in the background.